# JsHint error regarding Unsupported rule

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have following JavaScript function and I have to use syntax like below:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  function test(){
  }
}());
```

When I try to validate it with JsHint, it gives error:

> Unsupported rule: validateJSDoc at
>
> ```
>      1 |(function () {
> --------^
>      2 |    'use strict';
>      3 |
> ```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Please show your JSHint configuration.

Comment: Are you using the latest version?

Comment: yes i am using latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's JSHint? I had the exact same issue recently when upgrading JSCS.

If you are using JSCS be aware that `validateJSDoc` has been [deprecated](http://jscs.info/changelog#version-1-7-0-https-github-comjscs-devnode-jscscomparev1-6-0-v1-7-0). So it looks like your `.jscsrc` file still makes reference to `validateJSDoc`.

I just replaced `validateJSDoc` with `jsDoc` in `.jscsrc` and it worked ok.